# Div's won't go under eachother

Tags: html, css

I understand this has been asked before, however, previous questions are not helpful.

I currently have this

```css
body{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header{
    background-color: #00CACA;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
}

#middle-section{
    background-color: #FFAA00;
    position: relative; 
    height: 10vh;

}

#footer{
    background-color: #D0003F;
    position: relative; 

}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">
            <p>Header</p>
        </div>

        <div id="middle-section">
            <p>Middle section</p>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <p>Footer</p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

My objective is to have middle-section below the header and then footer below the middle-section. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: *Not helpful"*....how?

Comment: By either not using `position: fixed;` your `#header` or set a offset top on `#middle-section` with `margin` or `top`. But you better read up on [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) first.

Comment: you want to remove space between middle section and footer? your question not clear so much!

Comment: My goal is to have each div below each other one after the other to make different sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header{
    background-color: #00CACA;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#middle-section{
    background-color: #FFAA00;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;

}

#footer{
    background-color: #D0003F;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">
            <p>Header</p>
        </div>

        <div id="middle-section">
            <p>Middle section</p>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <p>Footer</p>
        </div>

    </div>
```